# Chrome: Strange scrollbar behaviour when adding dynamic content

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, overflow

27.04.2018 Update:
Seems like this has been resolved in Chrome v66. I am no longer able to reproduce this issue on this version.

--

In my web application I have custom context menus that load content asynchronously. These menus are flex divs with limited size and anything that doesn't fit should force scrollbar to show on the container (example resembling implementation below). Problem is that the scrollbar appears outside of the container unless (I guess) I force repaint of the website by resizing chrome window or changing css properties.

```js
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("list").item(0);

setTimeout(() => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div>TEST</div>");
  }
}, 0);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: lightgray
}

.surface {
    background-color: green;
    color: #343434;
    position: absolute;

    max-width: 50vw;
    max-height: 50vh;
    
    padding: 10px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.fill {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list {
  background: red;
}

.list.vertical > * {
  margin-bottom: 3mm;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="surface flex" style="left: 50%; top: 10%;">
    <div class="fill flex vertical spaced">
      <u>Text</u>
      <div class="fill flex vertical auto list">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wuj18nh4/2/

Once it's loaded you should notice the scrollbar being outside of the green container. If you force a repaint, the green container will grow in width and contain the scrollbar as it should.

My question is: is that a bug or broken css composition and how should I fix it without rewriting the whole structure?

Please note that it works correctly on Edge and latest Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The only change you have to do is you have to give `padding: 25px;` instead of `padding: 10px;`

```js
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("list").item(0);

setTimeout(() => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div>TEST</div>");
  }
}, 0);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: lightgray
}

.surface {
    background-color: green;
    color: #343434;
    position: absolute;

    max-width: 50vh;
    max-height: 50vh;
    
    padding: 25px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.fill {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.auto {
  overflow: auto;
}

.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list {
  background: red;
}

.list.vertical > * {
  margin-bottom: 3mm;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="surface flex" style="left: 50%; top: 10%;">
    <div class="fill flex vertical spaced">
      <u>Text</u>
      <div class="fill flex vertical auto list">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. Adding more padding is ugly workaround as it is still broken but contained inside because the scrollbar is smaller than the padding.